# Python Opening a different CSV file depending on an input

Tags: python, csv

Is there anyway to open and write to a CSV file depending on user input?

```
 new_record = [__Activity, __ActivityHours, __ActivitySpeed, __CaloriesBurned]
 writer = csv.writer(open("./user_info/" + Username + ".csv"), delimiter=',')
 writer.writerow(new_record)
```

I want a user to be able to click a button that opens their CSV file and writes to it.

Comment: Where does this button come from?  How is *their* CSV file being identified?

Answer (score 0):

To write to a file you need to add a second parameter to open, like open(filename,"w").
Note that "w" will truncate the file, while "a" will append to the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks Man, also, if I wantd to do math, how would I make (example) '50 x __NumberOfHours (NumberOfHours being an integer)